# Incorporating optional arrays in case parsing stage

Tags: bash

The following bash function fills items into arrays.

The syntax is

```
multary OPTIONS ary1 ary2 ary3 "item1" "item2" marker "item3" marker "item4"
```

The arrays `ary1`, `ary2`, `ary3` are optional.  I want to find a way to simplify the argument reading part so that the array parsing code in `PART2` is incorporated in the `CASE` part for processing positional arguments.

```
multary ()
 {
  ## Passing multiple arrays with marker between them.

  ## Marker as break
  local dna="***" dnb="***"

  while (( $# > 0 )); do
   parg="$1"
   case "$parg" in
     ("-m1") dna="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
     ("-m2") dnb="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
     ("--") shift 1 ; break ;;
     (*) break ;;
   esac
  done

  ##====================================================
  ## PART2

  if [[ "$(declare -p $1)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    typeset -n _ary1="$1"
    _ary1=() ; shift 1
    echo "_ary1 is an array"
  fi

  if [[ "$(declare -p $1)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    typeset -n _ary2="$1"
    _ary2=() ; shift 1
    echo "_ary2 is an array"
  fi

  if [[ "$(declare -p $1)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    typeset -n _ary3="$1"
    _ary3=() ; shift 1
    echo "_ary3 is an array"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need markers :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

multary(){
    while (( $# > 0 )); do
        case "$1" in
        ("-m") declare -n __ary="$2"; __ary=(); shift 2;;
        (*) __ary+=("$1"); shift;;
        esac
    done
}
multary -m ary1 "item1" "item2" -m ary2 "item3" -m ary3 "item4"
declare -p ary1
declare -p ary2
declare -p ary3
# Output :
# declare -a ary1=([0]="item1" [1]="item2")
# declare -a ary2=([0]="item3")
# declare -a ary3=([0]="item4")
```

Comment: You are using just a single array ` __ary`.  Is that robust enough to handle any number of optional arrays and values ?

Comment: That is only a temporary variable.

Comment: Understood.  A temporary variable that then updated the actual reference supplied as $2 in previous calls.  Every time the reference gets updated to corresponding actual variable passed to the function. I like it.

Comment: Perhaps the argument should be quoted with `__ary+=("$1")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

multary(){
        source <(
            awk '
                /^-m/{ f=1; getline arr; print arr"=()"; next }
                f{ print arr"+=("$0")" }
           ' < <(printf "%q\n" "$@")
        )
}

multary -m ary1 "item1 itemX" "item2" -m ary2 "item3" -m ary3 "item4"
declare -p ary1
declare -p ary2
declare -p ary3
```

---

```
# Output:
declare -a ary1=([0]="item1 itemX" [1]="item2")
declare -a ary2=([0]="item3")
declare -a ary3=([0]="item4")
```